# How do I search files containing a specific string using grep?

Tags: regex, grep

For instance, if a file has a line "blahblah myID=1234567 blahblah", I want to search all files containing 1234567 somewhere in the whole file.

I tried grep -r '.* 1234567.* ' directory, but it didn't work.

Comment: Tried `grep -r '1234567' /path/to/directory` ?

Comment: Are the spaces in what you tried just typos ?   grep -r '.*<space>1234567.*<space>' - because if they are what you typed, then grep would not find the lines like "=1234567"

Comment: There were no spaces. I added space because stackoverflow won't show .*

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

```
grep -rw 'directory' -e "pattern"
```

-r is recursive and -w stands match the whole word.

example

```
grep -rw '/home/lib/foldername/' -e "1234567"
```

you can also use `-n` which will tell you the line number where it matched the string

Comment: This is weird. I know there is a string "1234567" in a file in the current directory, but using grep -rw . -e "1234567" didn't return anything.  Then I copied the paragraph containing "1234567" to another file in another linux machine and do the same grep and found the string.

Comment: check for the right directory path...rather than . give proper directory path

Comment: I did try to use absolute path, same result. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
files=$(ls -l /dir |awk '/^-/ {print $NF}')
for i in $files
do
      cat $i | grep "1234567" >> output.txt
done
```

List files of /dir, and grep "1234567" and write to output.txt

Comment: You'd probably want '>>' rather than '>', otherwise output.txt will only contain the results for the last file